# db_update doesn't work with my code

Tags: database

Whith a custom module, I'd like to update some nodes uid whenever a content type is updated.
I triple checked, and my database update function is called, as "changed" field is updated each time, and I send myself a mail to check that the data passed is correct.

I don't know how to call the equivalent of `mysql_query() or die()`, and don't manage to debug that.

I have only a notice:

> Undefined index: #language dans `locale_field_node_form_submit()`.

```
function zen_custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  switch($form_id){
    case 'lieux_de_pratique_node_form':
      if (in_array('Admin dojos', array_values($user->roles))) {
        // some stuff
        $form['#submit'][]='set_dojos_manager';
        // ...
      }
      // ...
  }
  // ...
}

function set_dojos_manager($form, &$form_state) { 
  $dojo_editeur = $form['field_dojo_editeur_web']['und'][0]['uid']['#default_value'];
  $dojo = $form['nid']['#value'];
  $uid_updated = db_update('node')
    ->fields(array(
      'uid' => $dojo_editeur,
    ))
    ->condition('nid', $dojo)
    ->execute();

    mail('my_email', 'test', $dojo_editeur . ' / ' . $dojo);
  }
}
```

Comment: if you have devel installed try to put dsm in your submit callback and check whether you're getting proper values. Further note, why cant you use hook_node_update instead of form submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the way I solved it. I had to deactivate the *uid content type* synchronize. I added **hook_node_presave()** for insert nodes cases. I also assigned a role to the new user *uid* :

```
function zen_custom_node_update($node){
  switch($node->type){
    case 'lieux_de_pratique':
      global $user;
      if (in_array('Admin dojos', array_values($user->roles)) || in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
        $dojo = $node -> nid ;
        $dojo_editeur = $node -> field_dojo_editeur['und'][0]['uid'] ;
        db_update('node')
          ->fields(array(
            'uid' => $dojo_editeur,
          ))
          ->condition('tnid', $node->nid) //update all translations
          ->execute();
        //drupal_set_message($node->nid . ' node_update case:translated');
        $recipient = user_load($dojo_editeur); 
        user_multiple_role_edit(array($recipient -> uid), 'add_role', 11);
        drupal_set_message( 'Le compte <em>'. $recipient-> name . '</em> est &eacute;diteur de <em>' . $node -> title .'</em>');
      }
      break;
  }
}

function zen_custom_node_presave($node){//necessary for creating the first node of the translation set
  switch($node->type){
    case 'lieux_de_pratique':
      global $user;
      if (in_array('Admin dojos', array_values($user->roles)) || in_array('administrator', array_values($user->roles))) {
        $dojo_editeur = $node -> field_dojo_editeur['und'][0]['uid'] ;
        $node -> uid = $dojo_editeur;
        $recipient = user_load($dojo_editeur); 
        user_multiple_role_edit(array($recipient->uid ), 'add_role', 11);
      }
  break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your form submission handler should take the submitted values from `$form_state['values']`, not `$form`. The node object is then available in `$form_state['node']`.

For such task it would be better to implement [hook_node_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7), which is called right before a node is saved.

Comment: Well Thanks a lot. @Mathankumar yes I tripled checked the passed values. Following your advices, I rewrote it with **hook_node_presave()**. What succeed now is : the node is correctly modified, but it seems that the hook iterates on nodes with the same tnid, as far ad I can read into dsm , and returns an error, because the new uid value is empty after first update. I tried also with **hook_node_update()**, as I don't really understand the difference (?) but it returns the same error... May I put the new code in a answer?

Comment: In fact this is not exactly as I said above. With **hook_node_presave()** I have the same behavior than in my question : _changed_ timestamp is updated but not the uid. With **hook_node_update()**, the new _uid_ value is correctly imputed to the node, the old _uid_ is imputed to the following node which has same _tnid_, and the last node with same _tnid_ remains unchanged !!! It might be so because the translations for that _uid content type_ are synchronized... but why does the cursor changes for each node update? And again what diff between the two hooks ? Many thanks for your patience :)

Comment: There should not be any difference between those hooks, if there isn't a third-party module that is doing something particular, or "strange."

Comment: Well my code was not correct. Anyway I finally used both hooks, because I focused on update situations, forgetting the insert node situation. My code works great now, and I learned a lot, thanks again.